# Grafana configure AWS Account that has MFA active

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, amazon-athena

I would like to configure Grafana Athena AWS plugin but this datasource is only asking for Access Token and Secret Access Token.

The problem is that my account use MFA so I have to put also aws_session_token to make the connection work otherwise it tell me AccessDenied.

How can I do ? thanks

[image]

Comment: Why you don't use IAM role?

Comment: What do you mean? Should I fill "Assume Role ARN" ?